# Puppet agent certificate verify failure for new agents, but existing agents work fine (Puppet 7)

Tags: ssl, puppet

I have over 200 hosts presently working correctly against my puppet master (`puppet agent -t` applies a catalog).  However, starting sometime recently I can no longer add new hosts. There have been no changes on the server except for regular `apt upgrade`.  I've already attempted to downgrade puppetserver and puppet-agent.  Autosigning is turned on.

**Note** that the usual "delete agent certs and retry" approach did not work.  I also do not want to regenerate server certs if I can help it, since I will need to manually fix hundreds of agents if I do.

### Puppet Server

- Ubuntu 20.04
- puppetserver 7.15  (no intermediate cert)
- puppet-agent 7.28

### Agents

- Various Linux/Windows distributions with puppet 7 installed (multiple versions), all seem to be affected.

## Various Experiments

### Windows 11 Agent:

(After deleting agent's SSL directory)

```
C:\Windows\system32>puppet agent -t
Info: Certificate revocation is disabled, skipping CRL download
Info: Creating a new RSA SSL key for YYYYY
Info: csr_attributes file loading from C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/csr_attributes.yaml
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for YYYYY
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): 49:29:6C:59:21:EE:0B:46:17:58:56:FA:A1:C8:91:1D:77:5A:3A:25:9E:41:00:F1:43:6A:E1:31:39:3C:C3:44
Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get local issuer certificate for CN=XXXX]
Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get local issuer certificate for CN=XXXX]


C:\Windows\system32>puppet ssl verify
Error: Could not run: The client certificate is missing from 'C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc/ssl/certs/XXXX.pem'
```

But, if I copy `c:\programdata\puppetlabs\puppet\etc\ssl\certs\ca.pem` from a working system:

```
C:\Windows\system32>puppet ssl verify
Notice: Verified CA certificate 'CN=Puppet CA: XXXXX' fingerprint (SHA256) 51:E9:79:71:13:92:55:63:07:35:95:D4:95:36:5F:4C:7C:6F:80:D4:EF:18:08:C0:FE:D4:4F:9B:27:12
Notice: Verified client certificate 'CN=YYYY' fingerprint (SHA256) DF:A4:66:92:C0:24:B9:ED:42:C6:B9:53:02:25:DB:45:E3:FA:92:EB:AD:60:2D:D1:19:E2:3A:AF:B0:AD
```

Oddly, the output from `curl -k https://YYYY:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca` contains only one certificate, while working systems **have two in their ca.pem**

### Ubuntu Jammy in Docker

It's faster to test this in docker:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update ; apt -y install wget curl
RUN wget 'https://apt.puppet.com/puppet7-release-jammy.deb' && apt install ./puppet7-release-jammy.deb
RUN apt update ; apt -y install puppet-agent
RUN /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent -t --server YYYY
```

```
 > [5/5] RUN /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet agent -t --server XXXX:
1.447 Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get local issuer certificate for CN=YYYY]
1.448 Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get local issuer certificate for CN=YYYY]
```

Nothing interesting in the puppetserver log when I try all of the above.

**Even weirder**:  If I take a working (Windows) agent and clone it to a new machine (and change the hostname), all its pem files are zero-byte after the next puppet run.

## ca_crt.pem

My working agents have a `ca.pem` that matches /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca.pem of the the puppetserver.  However, `curl -k https://YYYY:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca` returns a different one (it returns the contents of `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/ca_crt.pem`).  Once I replaced it:

`cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem > /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/ca_crt.pem`

I got a different error on new agents:

`Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get certificate CRL for CN=YYYY]`

So far, I haven't found a way to regenerate CRLs, but what I did discover is that the main host cert (`/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/YYYY.pem`) has the wrong hostname it.

This leaves questions:

- Why did this break all of a sudden?  Nothing changed recently.
- Can I regenerate the host cert without breaking every agent?
- Can I just regenerate the CRL in Puppet 7?  I found [instructions for puppet 5](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/5.3/intermediate_ca_configuration.html#) but not 7.

Thanks for any pointers